# Limit of a summation with floor

Tags: limits

Could somebody help me with the limit below:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor}{n^{2}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Some of your notation was a little strange; please check to make sure that I interpreted it correctly.

Comment: Have a look now.  lim(n→∞) (∑(0→∞)⌊n/2⌋)/n^2

Comment: In fact what I'm trying to find out is the probability of something (which I believe is the formula above, but I might be wrong).<br/>I need to choose a winner of a contest, lets say with 1000 participants. Each one has 1/1000 chances to win. But then I'm asked to give 1 more chance of winning to those who purchased something. <br/> Initially I thought of assigning a random number between 0 and 1 with 12-15 decimal positions to each participant. Once I had the new requirement (2 chances for those who purchased)

Comment: I thought that they'll double the chances, therefore multiplying the random number by 2 will solve my issue. But it's not the right answer.  I was doing some simple calculations with a dice and 2 customers and got to the limit showed above.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will help you.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor}{n^{2}}\ge \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\frac{n}{2}-1}{n^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\;.$$

And and the harmonic series is diverges so the original series diverges.

Comment: To get $\ge$ and $\le$, use `\ge` and `\le`.

Comment: Thanks i have just edited my comment.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n^2}=0+\frac14+\frac19+\frac2{16}+\frac2{25}+\ldots=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac1{(2n)^2}+\frac1{(2n+1)^2}\right)=$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{8n^3+4n^2+n}{16n^4+16n^3+4n^2}$$

Now just observe that

$$\frac{8n^3+4n^2+n}{16n^4+16n^3+4n^2}\ge\frac{8n^3}{36n^4}=\frac2{9n}$$

and use the comparison test